# Is there any guide showing how to build effectively an application with appengine and maven in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop an application using Google App-Engine and Maven using Eclipse. I am facing a problem where by whenever you change a CSS or JSP file, a restart of the application is required. This makes working quite difficult, since a reload takes a lot of time.

For example when you develop on tomcat no need for restart is required when such a change is made, only Java or xml file require restart of the server.

Is there a solution that mimics the tomcat behavior on GAE SDK when developing on localhost?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, it's a very valid question (if anything, your title should be more descriptive to indicate what you are really interested in is how to get JSPs to reload without restarting the devserver)

Comment: I really don't understand how people could develop for appengine locally... I don't think is a dumb question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building application with appengine in eclipse using maven is not very effective and time consuming because on every change on jsp/css/js with a traditional approach there is a need to restart appengine or mvn appengine:devserver.

@adevine make me thought about a solution, and I found this link: http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html wich installs a plugin in eclipse, then I activate the project to sync files from myapp/src/main/webapp to a target folder generated by maven myapp/target/myapp-snapshot-0.0.1.

It's working!!!

Whenever a change is done in webapp the files are transfered automtically(no need to run anything else, just save the file) to the target folder and are reloaded successfully.

Hope this could help people because its frustrating working with appengine(restarts takes a lot).

Answer (score 1):

If you've built using the standard app engine maven archetype, when you run `mvn appengine:devserver` from you -ear directory, the exploded war working directory is located here:

```
<yourapp>/<yourapp>-ear/target/<yourapp>-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/<yourapp>-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

If you change any JSPs in this directory, they will get reloaded without needing to restart the devserver.

Thus, you can set up a simple script or command that copies all your JSPs and static files from /-war/src/main/webapp to that deploy directory whenever you want your files to be refreshed. I saw on some threads where people set up their IDE (in this case IntelliJ) to automatically do that copy whenever the IDE loses focuses, which makes it trivial to get pages reloaded.

Comment: So in other words I have to create a script to copy files from main folder to target folder :) Really? There is no maven plugin to do this?

Comment: Seriously? It's a one line cp statement in bash. How much easier do you want it?

Comment: I thought using eclipse on save event to be able to make this change, its not a best practice when you save a document to run a script to make a project work, maven should do this I think. Something similar to IntelliJ is nice maybe in eclipse :)